# Adding React to an existing php file/project

Tags: php, reactjs, jsx

I've been trying to add react form on an already existing php page. I have followed this [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

If I run a `console.log("Tried this.")` within script tags in the main/parent PHP file I get to see "Tried this." in the console,which is what I expected. However,when I `<script src ="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>` to load the external form.js file it doesn't get loaded. Here is the external index.js I am trying to load.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Form from './Form';


ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is the exported Form function I want to be rendered but can't get rendered.

```js
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Form extends Component {
    render() {


        console.log("Testing")

        return (
            <div>

                <h3>Testing</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

I am failing to notice what I'm missing.Please help.

Comment: You seem to be going the "quickly try JSX" route in https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx – did you also add Babel?

Comment: Yes I did.  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

Comment: Maybe add all that to your post too... Also, do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Okay,thanks. Let me add them.